# UITableView in storyboard not updating content size on rotation

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, autolayout, contentsize

I'm working on project targeted for iOS 6 that leverages storyboards and auto layout. In the storyboard there are many places where a UITableView is added as a subview to a view controllers view. This table view uses prototype cells from the storyboard.

The issue we're running into is that if the view controller is initially loaded in landscape orientation and the device is then rotated to portrait, the table view begins to scroll both vertically and horizontally. The table views cells are drawn with the correct dimensions but there is additional white space to the right.

It appears that while the frame and bounds of the table view are being updated to the correct size on rotation, the table views content size is not. Regardless of any update rotation change the content size remains the same dimensions.

The issue doesn't present itself if programatic table view cells are used.
A few garish work arounds I've found, 1.) calling      reloadData or    reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:  2.) manually setting the property contentSize.

Both of these seem less than ideal.

I've added this
[link to a dead simple sample project](http://bit.ly/ScDIaU) which demonstrates this issue. The only changes made are to the storyboard and the main view controllers implementation.

Before rotation
[image: Before rotation]
After rotation
[image: After rotation]

Comment: I'm confused. In your example it seems to be working.

Comment: @mkral it's broken for me when running Xcode 4.5. If you launch the app in landscape, then rotate to portrait, the table view will then scroll both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: OK, I'm dumb. I thougt portrait-to-landscape was the problem. I never went back.

Comment: This happens when loading from nib as well. Couldn't repro on iOS 7 though.

Answer (score 5):

I'm having the same issue - can't seems to find any documented answer related to this.  I ended up manually modifying the UITableView contentSize like you mentioned in:

```
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.height, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
}
```

Comment: I can't make this work for my issue.  I'm seeing fundamentally the same problem, in the Master-Detail layout.  I have a UIViewController in the Detail Controller, which contains a tableview.  When I rotate the iPad, the tableview simply will not resize.

Comment: I'm reading Ray Wenderlich's iOS6 Tutorials, and the auto-layout stuff has something specific about tables.  Haven't tried it out yet, but it looks like the table stuff may actually have to be set up separately, and then loaded into a container in the UIViewController.

I'm not sure about this at all.  Hoping to get to it later this afternoon.  If I find anything definitive, I'll update here.

Comment: Try using **- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews]; self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.height, self.tableView.contentSize.height);}**

Comment: Firstly, I'm guessing the contentSize width should be equal to tableView's width and not height. Secondly, this doesn't work as at this point the screen isn't rotated yet so the frame size doesn't reflect the final layout. This won't work in the viewDidLayout either as that triggers an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today and filed a bug report with Apple.

Appears that if you are using a custom cell with a UI element AND autoLayout, the UIScrollView content size is having problems.

If you remove all UI elements, OR turn off autoLayout, OR use a factory cell (basic, etc), all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I have rectified in my project. 
I guess this is a bug in Storyboard.

Then I have solved it by manual coding in willAutorotate method by setting

```
tableview.contentsize = CGSizeMake(tableview.width, tableview.contentsize.height);
```

Hope this will work for you as well.

If you find any apple documentation regarding the same then please update me as well. Till then you can use the same solution.

Comment: Which link? What you want to say?

Answer (score 0):

> Appears that if you are using a custom cell with a UI element AND autoLayout, the UIScrollView content size is having problems.

I had to turn off AutoLayout for my custom UITableViewCells to be able to scroll to the bottom on updating the data and then [self.tableView reloadData].

With AutoLayout turned on, the tableView.contentSize was being updated, but I still wasn't able to scroll to the bottom unless I rotated the device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I found [this](http://www.coursehero.com/courses/122/concept/3973/Handling-Rotation-in-Interface-Builder/) link. When I tried to implement this I did not find the Auto-sizing attributes for my view then I clicked on `Master View Controller` and then clicked on the `File Inspector` and uncheck `Use Autolayout` and then go to `Attributes inspector` auto-resizing should be there then you can change the attributes how you want it.

I am sure you must have managed to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to work for me:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
    });
}
```

Notice the async dispatch: if that line would be executed synchronously then the contentSize change would trigger another layout pass before the current one would have completed. This triggers an exception:

> Auto Layout still required after sending -viewDidLayoutSubviews to the
>   view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of **Constraints** helped me. Since you are using Storyboards, it is really easy to set Constraint values for all edges, so UITableView will always fill the whole ViewController (of course if UITableView fills whole ViewController) regardless of device orientation.